# What does "0 rows" mean when running a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration, rails-migrations

I just ran a migration that adds several indexes to several tables. Every single one results in this "-> 0 rows" output:

```
Migrating to AddVariousIndexesOctober2014 (20141103195036)
== 20141103195036 AddVariousIndexesOctober2014: migrating =====================
-- add_index(:foo, [:bar, :baz])
   -> 0.0240s
   -> 0 rows
…
```

I don't remember ever seeing something like this before.

Inspecting the database, the data is non-zero as expected and the index additions seem to have worked as expected.

what does "-> 0 rows" mean?

Comment: My guess is it's returning the "number of rows affected" which for indexes would be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an index to a table doesn't change any rows in the table, so it's normal to see `0 rows` here. If you changed a column, then you would see a non-zero number, since this would affect all rows in the table.